# CUDA stack frame size increase by __forceinline__

Tags: cuda, nvcc

When I declare device functions with `__forceinline__`, the linker outputs this information:

```
2>  nvlink : info : Function properties for '_ZN3GPU4Flux4calcILj512EEEvv':
2>  nvlink : info : used 28 registers, 456 stack, 15776 bytes smem, 320 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem
```

and without it the output is:

```
2>  nvlink : info : Function properties for '_ZN3GPU4Flux4calcILj512EEEvv':
2>  nvlink : info : used 23 registers, 216 stack, 15776 bytes smem, 320 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem
```

Why is the size of the stack frame smaller when the `__forceinline__` is not used?
How important is to keep the stack frame as small as possible?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is impossible to answer the first question, as you are not providing any information on the involved `__global__` and `__device__` functions. An answer to the second question can be given and is reported below. Please, visit the [CUDA Tag Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) for details on how getting useful answers. Quoting the CUDA Tag Info: _Include an as-simple-as-possible code example in your question and you are much more likely to get a useful answer. If the code is short and self-contained (so users can test it themselves), that is even better._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to reduce the stack frame is that the stack is allocated in local memory which resides in off-chip device memory. This makes the access to the stack (if not cached) slow.

To show this, let me make a simple example. Consider the case:

```
__device__ __noinline__ void func(float* d_a, float* test, int tid) {
    d_a[tid]=test[tid]*d_a[tid];
}

__global__ void kernel_function(float* d_a) {
    float test[16];
    test[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
    func(d_a,test,threadIdx.x);
}
```

Note that the `__device__` function is declared `__noinline__`. In this case

```
ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z15kernel_functionPf
    64 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas : info : Used 7 registers, 36 bytes cmem[0]
```

i.e., we have `64` bytes of stack frame. The corresponding disassembled code is

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
ISUB R1, R1, 0x40;
S2R R6, SR_TID.X;                    R6 = ThreadIdx.x
MOV R4, c[0x0][0x20];
IADD R5, R1, c[0x0][0x4];
I2F.F32.U32 R2, R6;                  R2 = R6 (integer to float conversion)              
ISCADD R0, R6, R1, 0x2;
STL [R0], R2;                        stores R2 to test[ThreadIdx.x]                                
CAL 0x50; 
EXIT ;                               __device__ function part
ISCADD R2, R6, R5, 0x2;
ISCADD R3, R6, R4, 0x2;
LD R2, [R2];                         loads d_a[tid]
LD R0, [R3];                         loads test[tid]
FMUL R0, R2, R0;                     d_a[tid] = d_a[tid]*test[tid]
ST [R3], R0;                         store the new value of d_a[tid] to global memory
RET ;
```

As you can see, `test` is stored and loaded from global memory, forming the stack frame (it is `16 floats = 64 bytes`).

Now change the device function to

```
__device__ __forceinline__ void func(float* d_a, float* test, int tid) {
    d_a[tid]=test[tid]*d_a[tid];
}
```

that is, change the `__device__` function from `__noinline__` to `__forceinline__`. In this case, we have

```
ptxas : info : Compiling entry function '_Z15kernel_functionPf' for 'sm_20'
ptxas : info : Function properties for _Z15kernel_functionPf
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
```

i.e., we have an empty stack frame now. Indeed, the disassembled code becomes:

```
MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];               
S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                    R2 = ThreadIdx.x
ISCADD R3, R2, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;    
I2F.F32.U32 R2, R2;                  R2 = R2 (integer to float conversion)
LD R0, [R3];                         R2 = d_a[ThreadIdx.x] (load from global memory)
FMUL R0, R2, R0;                     d_a[ThreadIdx.x] = d_a[ThreadIdx.x] * ThreadIdx.x
ST [R3], R0;                         stores the new value of d_a[ThreadIdx.x] to global memory
EXIT ;
```

As you can see, forcing the inlining enables the compiler to perform proper optimizations so that now `test` is fully discarded from the code.

In the above example, `__forceinline__` has an effect that is opposite to what you are experiencing, which also shows that, without any further information, the first question cannot be answered.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The reason why I did not post the code is that it is long and complicated. The thing which seemed little weird for me was that, when I am removed the __force_inline__ modifiers, the compiler reduced the stack frame. Later I realized that I was compiling with debug mode enabled. In release mode it is ok.

Comment: If that's the case, why would not to define force inline as default, What are the disadvantages in force inline